# Solve the following system in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, integers

I want to find $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $xy-z^2=161$ and $xz-yz=7$. I know that the solution is $x=15,y=14,z=7$ by using elementary aritmethics. But, is there a geometric way to solve this problem? I mean, a not traditional way.

Comment: Geometric way? What do you mean?

Comment: Since $(x-y)z=7$ then $z=1$ or $z=7$ is forced in integer solutions, and this leads quasi immediately to the overall solution. Geometrically only "simple" way to make sum of products is via dotproduct or cross product. So have a try with vectors $(x,y,0)$ and $(z,z,0)$ or similar.

Comment: This is the way I have solved the problem, but I would like to do it in another different way

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}^3$ will have 'gaps' in between the numbers unlike any Euclidean space. Thus, you can visualize this as:

1. First plot the graphs of the equations in the standard $\mathbb{R}^3$ setting.
2. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the intersection of the two curves would be your solution.

Now, 'cut' down the unwanted elements, $\mathbb{N}^c$ to be precise where $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$. This would give discontinuous curves which intersect only at the points which are in $\mathbb{N}^3$, if any.

That's the idea behind solving it 'geometrically' from what I have understood from your question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use any computer to solve the problem

Comment: Then graph it manually! It will be a tedious task, I think my answer helped you to visualize what is happening.

Comment: @galba no one is asking you to use computer. Put it manually!
1. $z^2 = -161+(2\times3)=-155$. Now, check if this $z$ is in $\mathbb{N}$. Keep doing the tedious task until you find one. Not understanding why are you self inflicting unnecessary complication. Thanks. :)